# (iphone) submit an app update just to change keywords?

Tags: iphone, keyword

I wonder if it's legitimate to submit an app update just to change keywords.

My app name is 'first second' and it's not searchable with 'first second' nor 'firstsecond'.
I suspect adding 'firstsecond' as one of keywords might be better.

-edit

The unsearchability  was due to the synchronization delay I suppose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have to resubmit your app to change keywords unfortunately. Your app will not be searchable immediately after being approved by the keywords, it may take a few days to populate in the system.

Comment: Will it allow to change the keyword while updating the app to a a new version? or I will have to delete the binary and resubmit it again?

Comment: As long as your app is in an editable state (new version), then you can change keywords on the new version. The old version keywords will stay the same until the new version is approved.